# What does the error "Event [isTrusted .... ]" mean in p5.js?

Tags: javascript

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNRYT.jpg) is the error. It ran fine before, then I tweaked the code but I removed the tweak and I still get this error. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwyH3.jpg) is what the expanded version looks like.

If it matters, what I tweaked with wasn't on the main screen shown here, it was on Screen 1. I'm using p5.js code editor.

Comment: That's not an error. It's the output of `console.log()` of an `Event` object.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.